# Large scale map projection (ca. 20 km) in pyproj results in wrong distance

Tags: coordinate-system, pyproj

I would like to transform from lon/lat (EPSG:4326) to a local x/y coordinate system for large scale equidistant maps with a map size of ca. 20 km. I need to do this mapping all over the globe apart from regions close to the poles.
Looking at https://projectionwizard.org/ it suggests for 1x1 degs something like `+proj=cass +lon_0=-121.5 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`.

However, when looking at distances e.g. high up in Norway, the distances are way off. I must be doing something wrong, but I have no clue what it is.

```
self.trans_proj = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(
  'EPSG:4326',
  {
    'proj': 'cass',  # tmerc
    'x_0': '500000.0',
    'lon_0': str(self._lon),
    'lat_0': str(self._lat),
    'k_0': '0.9999',
    'datum': 'WGS84'
  }
)

x, y, = self.trans_proj.transform(lon, lat, radians=False)
```

I set the lon_0 and lat_0 attributes to the current lon/lat of the centre of the map.

Comment: `+proj=cass` is cassini projection that only preserves (arc of greatcircle) distances in direction +-90 degrees from the central meridian of the projection.

Answer (score 2):

Using `always_xy=True` as the third parameter in the `.from_crs()` method solved the problem.